# Unble to locate the dynamic search result using Selenium java

Tags: java, selenium, automation

I am trying to validate search results with searched values. There's a table which displays all the existing keywords. When particular keyword is need to be listed user can search the keyword. search results are displayed in the same table which all keywords were listed before searching.

In particularly when I search for keyword android, "android headlines" and "android" keywords are displayed in the table body. I got the location of  these two elements using xpath and printed in the console.But in the console it displays as "Description" and "Oppo" which displays in 1st and 2nd row which had all the keywords listed.

below is the HTML code.

```
<div id="keyword-grid" class="grid-view">
   <table class="items table table-striped">
      <thead>
         <tr>
            <th id="keyword-grid_c0"><a class="sort-link" href="/index.php/keyword/Admin?Keyword_sort=name">Name<span class="caret"></span></a></th>
            <th id="keyword-grid_c1"><a class="sort-link" href="/index.php/keyword/Admin?Keyword_sort=behaviour">Behaviour<span class="caret"></span></a></th>
            <th id="keyword-grid_c2"><a class="sort-link" href="/index.php/keyword/Admin?Keyword_sort=status">Status<span class="caret"></span></a></th>
            <th id="keyword-grid_c3"><a class="sort-link" href="/index.php/keyword/Admin?Keyword_sort=createdAt">Created At<span class="caret"></span></a></th>
            <th id="keyword-grid_c4"><a class="sort-link" href="/index.php/keyword/Admin?Keyword_sort=createdBy">Created By<span class="caret"></span></a></th>
            <th class="button-column" id="keyword-grid_c5">&nbsp;</th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
         <tr class="odd">
            <td>Description</td>
            <td>Manual</td>
            <td><span class="badge badge-success">Active</span></td>
            <td>2018-01-16 05:48:02</td>
            <td>Admin</td>
            <td class="button-column"><a class="view" title="View" rel="tooltip" href="/index.php/keyword/View/163"><i class="icon-eye-open"></i></a>  </td>

         <tr class="odd">
            <td>Oppo</td>
            <td>Manual</td>
            <td><span class="badge badge-success">Active</span></td>
            <td>2017-11-16 06:32:19</td>
            <td>Digitalbox Testing</td>
            <td class="button-column"><a class="view" title="View" rel="tooltip" href="/index.php/keyword/View/161"><i class="icon-eye-open"></i></a>  </td>
         </tr>
         <tr class="even">
            <td>android headlines</td>
            <td>Manual</td>
            <td><span class="badge badge-success">Active</span></td>
            <td>2017-11-15 07:53:02</td>
            <td>Admin</td>
            <td class="button-column"><a class="view" title="View" rel="tooltip" href="/index.php/keyword/View/160"><i class="icon-eye-open"></i></a>  </td>
         </tr>
         <tr class="odd">
            <td>api</td>
            <td>Manual</td>
            <td><span class="badge badge-success">Active</span></td>
            <td>2017-11-15 07:53:02</td>
            <td>Admin</td>
            <td class="button-column"><a class="view" title="View" rel="tooltip" href="/index.php/keyword/View/159"><i class="icon-eye-open"></i></a>  </td>
         </tr>
         <tr class="even">
            <td>android</td>
            <td>Manual</td>
            <td><span class="badge badge-important">Deleted</span></td>
            <td>2017-11-09 09:43:50</td>
            <td>Admin</td>
            <td class="button-column"><a class="view" title="View" rel="tooltip" href="/index.php/keyword/View/158"><i class="icon-eye-open"></i></a>  </td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
```

This is the code I tried to get searched results.

```
driver1.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"keyword-grid\"]/table/tbody/tr[1]"));
driver1.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"keyword-grid\"]/table/tbody/tr[2]"));
System.out.print(driver1.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"keyword-grid\"]/table/tbody/tr[1]")).getText());
System.out.print(driver1.findElement(By.xpath( "//*[@id=\"keyword-grid\"]/table/tbody/tr[2]")).getText());
```

How can I print the results of android search?

Comment: please give us more details on your requirement?

Comment: Can you update the question with the exact `Manual Steps` you are trying to `Automate`?

Comment: is it updating values in same table?

Comment: yes.it displays in the same table.

Comment: But in html, i am not able to find the word android anywhere?

Comment: It's there.In the table rows.android is the keyword name.

Comment: from your HTML tr[1] and tr[2] have Description and Oppo. tr[3] is the one that contains android. Or am I missing something?

Comment: When I search the word android only android headlines and android keywords will stay in the table no other data. When I got the location it displays android headline location as tr[1] but in the console it prints as Description not as android headlines.